# Decrypt SHA1 Base64 Hash

Tags: encryption, hash

After spending a good hour searching I came across an article that explained that you can't reverse a hash value. How true is this? I need to reverse a base64 encoded Sha-1 email address but I can't seem to find a way without knowing what function was used to hash. Or is there an easier way of going about this?

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. You say you don't know what function was used to hash, but you say it's a SHA-1 hash...so you know SHA-1 was used to hash.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. Any thoughts on reversing the hash?

Comment: I suggest reading [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). How true is it for SHA-1 if you know nothing about the input? Unlikely that you can reverse it before our sun burns out - even if you had all the computers in the world. SHA-1 is inescure and there were interesting results recently - but breaking preimage resistance is on an entirely different level.

Answer (score 2):

- You can very easily Base64-decode a string.
- SHA-1 was designed to *prevent* people from inverting it. It approximates a [one-way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function).

[See here for more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117581/why-md5-sha1-password-hashes-cannot-be-decrypted) If it could be simply inverted, it would provide no information security.

Your only feasible option is brute-force search.

Comment: And don't forget to google the hash (as hex preferably), sometimes some DBs will have the string...